# Spark Persist method odd behavior

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I am exploring spark persist function. It seems for some dataframe it is persisting whereas for others it is not, even though I have used the persist method on all the dataframes

Here is my code with explaination

```
// loading csv as dataframe and creating a view
val src_data=spark.read.option("header",true).csv("sources/data.csv")
src_data.createTempView("src_data")

**There is alreading a table called test in hive**

Here I am creating 3 dataframes using src and test and using persist on all 3 for later use
//dataframe 1
val changed_data= spark.sql("select sc.* from src_data sc inner join default.test t on sc.id=t.id where t.value!=sc.value or t.description!=sc.description ")
   changed_data.persist().show()
   changed_data.createOrReplaceTempView("changed_data")

// dataframe 2
 val new_data= spark.sql("select * from src_data where id not in (select distinct id from default.test)")
   println("new_data")
   new_data.persist().show()
   new_data.createOrReplaceTempView("new_data")

// dataframe 3
 val unchanged_data= spark.sql("select * from test where id not in (select id from changed_data)")
   unchanged_data.persist().show()
   unchanged_data.createTempView("unchanged_data")


**then I truncate the table test** 
spark.sql("truncate table test")

***Then i print the 3 dataframes I persisted***

new_data.show()
unchanged_data.show()
changed_data.show()
```

Before truncating test I can see data for all 3 dataframes using show but after I see only data for one dataframe....
I get data for only new_data(which is dataframe 2) eventhough I persisted all 3 dataframes and all three use table test??

Why this odd behaviour

Comment: `persist` does not do what you seem to think it does. Think of it as a "cache". Once you empty the `test`, "cache" becomes "dirty", and is invalidated. So, when you look the dfs again, those that rely on inner join with the (now empty) `test` are understandably also empty.

Comment: Thanks, but dataframe 2 also uses test in the where condition ,but I get the correct result even after truncating test..

Comment: It uses test is in `id not in (select id from test)`, which ends up being true for every row, once you empty the test.

Comment: You are correct. But I am not getting every row. It seems like the test table is available for dataframe 2 but not for others...  Also without persisting dataframe 2 , I get all the rows after truncating test which makes sense..

Comment: Then I don't know ... Sounds like magic :)

Answer (score 0):

The Dataframes will only be persisted if you invoke an action that goes through **every record** of the Dataframe.

Remember, that `show()` only shows the Top 20 rows as documented in the [ScalaDocs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#show():Unit).

In contrast, you could apply something like `count()` but that obviously will have some negative impact on your performance.

Comment: The number records in all the dataframe is less than 20..